# Flash Media Server 4.5 or any

Tags: flash, video, rtmp, flash-media-server

I have set up Flash Media Server 4.5 (Local PC, no Amazon or any Online Service). Remote location (same LAN) streaming live to the server using analog capture cards with Adobe Flash Media Encoder.
The locations is streaming to the following rtmp url.

> FMS URL: "rtmp://server-ip/live"
>
> Stream Name: "stream1"

From a website i have use jwplayer to play that stream and that is okay. The problem comes when i want to record during live streaming.

How to achieve that? The player doesn't support recording, "is just a player".

Is there any way to capture and save to a local folder a portion of the live stream during live streaming?
Notice that Flash Media Server uses Server-Client side Actionscript.

Please if can anyone help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using [**`VLC`**](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) (free application) to play & record the stream. Open the stream as `rtmp://server-ip/live/stream1` and it will play. I'm sure you will find the "record" button...

Answer (score 0):

Better solution to record Flash Media Server or any other RTMP Media LIVE Stream is to use **rtmpdump** https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/. You can get its command line [documentation](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/rtmpdump.1.html) for reference. 
For example to record the **live** stream with parameters

```
FMS URL: "rtmp://server-ip/live"

Stream Name: "stream1"
```

You can use following command

```
rtmpdump −r rtmp://server-ip/live/stream1 -v −o somefile.mp4
```

We used the following options here

1. **-r** for specifying url.
2. **-v** for specifying for LIVE stream.
3. **-o** for rending output for a file. You can play this file in VLC Player or any other MP4 player. You should file extension to match your encoding settings.

Optional Tip:
*You can also Record stream from Microsoft Media Server from [here](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/ms-rtsp-dump/)*